# How to prevent sbt from running a task multiple times in a session?

Tags: sbt

I'd like to prevent the following task from getting run multiple times when sbt is running:

```
val myTask = someSettings map {s => if !s.isDone doSomethingAndSetTheFlag}
```

So what's expected would be when myTask is run for the first time, isDone is false and something gets done in the task, and then the task sets the flag to true. But when the task is run for the second time, since the isDone flag is true, it skips the actual execution block.

The expected behavior is similar to compile -> when source is compiled, the task doesn't compile the code again the next time it's triggered until watchSource task says the code has been changed.

Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

This is done by sbt, a task will be evaluated only once within a single run. If you want to have a value evaluated once, at the project load time, you can change it to be a [SettingKey](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.1/docs/Getting-Started/Custom-Settings.html#defining-a-key).

This is documented in the [sbt documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Tasks.html#Defining+a+basic+task) (highlighting is mine):

> As mentioned in the introduction, a task is evaluated on demand. Each
>   time sampleTask is invoked, for example, it will print the sum. If the
>   username changes between runs, stringTask will take different values
>   in those separate runs. (**Within a run, each task is evaluated at
>   most once.**) In contrast, settings are evaluated once on project load
>   and are fixed until the next reload.

Comment: thanks for the answer however that's not exactly what I'm asking (my question was confusing. I apologize for that). I've edited the question and could you take a look again?

Comment: @NSF may I ask what exactly do you want to do? If this is to be evaluated only once, and not to depend on any input changes, why don't you want to make it a setting. If the task you have depends on an input (like e.g. compile), this is a different story. Does it?

Comment: So the execution block in myTask (say, specific resource generation) would take a long time to run (say, 20 secs) and I've let compile depend on it, in which case, whenever compile is run, the task is triggered. However I wanna make it run only once (i.e. the first time compile is run during one session).

Comment: Does the task have some product? If so, you can cache the product, and every time the task is run besides the first, return the cached thing. So the task still runs multiple times, but it only actually does any work once. This is how a task such as `compile` behaves — if there's nothing to recompile, the task runs, but doesn't do any work.